# How to remove a Joytech freehub (5mm allen key version)

Tags: maintenance, freehub

I've been trying to remove broken my joytech freehub (from an 11 speed felt b16) for a frustratingly long time.  The model in question takes two 5mm allen keys, and is not the same as the seemingly more common one, which takes an 11mm allen key to remove, like these  [here](https://www.bikeradar.com/gear/article/how-to-overhaul-your-freehub-23757/) and [here](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/54297/what-tool-do-i-need-to-remove-this-joytech-freehub)

I have successfully removed what look to be seals from each side, but I am now stuck with two holes which receive a 5mm allen key, but that will not budge, to the point i'm concerned that maybe they're reverse threaded and don't want to apply too much force.

Here are two pictures of the drive side:
[image]

and the back side:
[image]

As i say, both sides take 5mm allen keys. Can anyone shed any light on how to remove this type of hub?

Comment: If this some sort of single speed or fixed gear hub?

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus nope, its an 11 speed  from a felt b16 (road/triathlon bike)

Comment: Ah, you're trying to remove the *freehub body*. Looks like you are at the stage of getting the axle out before removing the freehub.

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus how would one go about this?

Comment: Try this https://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/freehub-service#article-section-6 (not posting as answer cos it's just a link). Does not mention Joytech but indicates the two 5mm hex slots in the ends of the axles are used by some hubs

Comment: Are the parts already removed aluminum endcaps that screw onto either side? There are some hubs where all those 5mm Allen flats are for is removing the second endcap once the first one is off. If you're sure the freehub can't just pull off at this stage, then the only other thing you can do is bonk out the axle, probably by hitting the exposed left tip. This may require you to replace/reinstall the right side main bearing.

Comment: I see flats in the hole - find the right allen/hex tool on each side and see how it goes opposing them.  You could also check the owner's manual.

Comment: @Criggie thanks for the response, this was my first thought too, but I've put a fair amount of force into opposing the allen keys and it's not budging, I'm concerned I'll break the Key if i put much more into it.  That said if it has flats, that must be for a purpose?

Comment: Could have loctite on the threads, normally you'd use blue (low strength) which resists vibration but can still be opened by hand tools.  Not impossible someone used red (ie a medium or higher strength) which requires several hundred degrees to soften.

Comment: I'm 99% confident they won't be reverse threadded.  Why?   Power through the chain serves to tighten everything in the days of a freewheel.  And cycle makers wouldn't ever change the direction of threadding in a part that is always in one direction for an obvious safety reason.   (not like bottom brackets!)

Comment: Why are you removing the freehub anyway?  If it needs service then failing to get it off means a new wheelhub (or even a complete new wheel)  So add leverage to your tools, and if it breaks you needed a new one anyway.

Comment: @Criggie The freehub is sticking, I'm thinking maybe its got some gunk in there and may be yet repairable.  On the replacement note, I've alreade bought a new one, just trying to salvage a turbo trainer wheel :) Thanks for the advice, I'll give it some juice tonight and add an answer if i find one

Comment: Note that "reverse threaded" for freehub bodies may mean something unexpected if you never removed one. :) (Most of them unscrew CW as seen from the right side of the bicycle)

Comment: I did not notice you already have a spare. You could investigate the threads on that, couldn't you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer the question, I had to give a sturdy tap to the axel from the back-side (though it looks like you could have gone from either end), which then popped out (leaving me able to remove the bearings) and left (what looks like) the 11mm allen key space to remove the freehub.

Update: you actually need a 12mm allen key (no need for the 11mm at all). You need to use the long part of the allen key (preferable keeping the short end in a vice) to loosen the larger interior receptor (12mm as opposed to 11mm, which is accessible from the drive side)

Comment: Great work - thank you for coming back and providing updates.   The park PH-11 is exactly the tool you want, but its not cheap.  I'd try a 10mm to see if that fits - is a more available tool size if nothing else.

Comment: Ah, interesting. So to remove any freehub with sealed bearings, you first have to tap the axle and bearings out? Where were the 5mm keys needed?

Comment: @RobertLisaru as i remember; 2 x 4 or 5mm keys were needed to loosen the dustcaps (turn them in opposite directions) to allow removal of the axel.